# Select all bones with a keyframe at a specific frame in the timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

In the dope sheet, I have a marker that tells me I have bones with a keyframe at a specific frame. I can scroll down the sheet to find them, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to do it?

My instinct would be to right-click the summary track and do something like "Select bones", but that is not an option.

Comment: I haven´t seen that function as far as i know. I usually select the bones manually using the Shift key in the Dope Sheet editor.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to select bones from selected keyframes that I know of.

But to be honest, the workflow is usually to only display the keys of the selected bones in the first place, which is done by toggling this button:

[image: display only selected]

Comment: I don't have any bone selected because I don't know which one has a key on that frame. I am looking for a way to automatically select the bones that have keys on the current frame. From your answer, I assume it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for this, think I figured it out.

Untick Only Show Selected, Expand Summary, then click on the bones listed, or hover your mouse over and hit A on the keyboard.
[image]

Comment: This is pretty good, except that it will show all the bones that have a key on the timeline, even if they don't have a key at the specific frame I am at.